# How can we change the particle size in Blender 2.8?

Tags: particles, workflow

I was watching the motion graphics tutorial, and there's a size adjustment for 2.78, but not 2.83. Where do I go to change the particle sizes now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change particle size from the Render drop-down in the particle properties or by scaling the instance object itself.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! <3